# Question about Time 1/Time 2 analysis

Tags: regression, time-series, anova, pre-post-comparison

I was hoping to get some input on the best way to test some data that I have collected (using SPSS).

In short, respondents make an evaluation at time 1, then complete a distractor task, and then complete an evaluation at time 2 (DV is a 1-7 scale). It is a 2x2 between subjects design where 2 variables are manipulated at time 2. There are likely several ways to approach this, but do you all have any suggestions for what may work best to analyze the differences between means at time 1 and time 2? And I suppose it is technically a repeated measures design, as respondents make 2 evaluations each.

Comment: What is your sample size?  Are all 7 scale values used? Are the distributions of your DV somewhat normal, within group?

Comment: Thanks for inquiring, Joel. Sample size is 120. Yes, all 7 scales values are used, and the distribution would be considered somewhat normal. Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could start by 'reducing' the repeated measures by considering a simple difference score, for example Time 2 - Time 1, for each respondent. This would give each respondent one score only, which you could then enter into a 2x2 ANOVA as the dependent variable.

An alternative is to run a 2x2x2 mixed ANOVA, where you use time as an additional within-subject factor.

I don't use SPSS but I recall that these are some of the easiest analyses to run with that software. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you respondents make two evaluations, you have a repeated measures design. I presume the two evaluations are due to different levels of one of your two factors. Since you have only 2 evaluations for each respondent, you must have a mixed between-within subjects design.  SPSS can handle that in the GLM procedure. If you are using drop down menus, click on analyse and then general linear model, and then repeated measures.  As you go through the options you have the opton to move a variable into the whting-subjects variables box.